# Error "token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression"

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

if I build and run a project, basically a stub generated by the Qt framework on Mac OS 10.6, I get this error output:

```
/Users/home/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/clang_64/include/QtCore/qisenum.h:53: Error:token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression
#    if __has_extension(is_enum)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

I can´t find a solution to this, although I read that other Mac users seem to have the same problem. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe the macro `__has_extension` is not implemented for `is_enum` or you need to find the definition.  Try `grep`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the hint, but is it really reasonable to hack arround in the code of the QT Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. Just copy the latest qisenum.h file [from here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,20748) and replace it in `clang_64/include/QtCore` folder in your `Qt` creator installation, it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved in [this forum post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.user/4899).

It is basically an issue with your version of clang

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> #    if __has_extension(is_enum)
>          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> ```

That's a Clang [language extension](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#feature-checking-macros) called [feature checking macros](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#feature-checking-macros). They've been around a long time for Clang. GCC provided them starting at GCC 5.0, IIRC.

`__has_extension` can be tested as a preprocessor macro. So you test for the presence of the macro first, and then you test for the feature:

```
#if defined(__has_extension)
# if __has_extension(is_enum)
   ...
# endif
#endif
```

`__has_extension(is_enum)` must be on a separate line.

It works for include files, too. From the Crypto++ project an [rdrand.cpp file](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/rdrand_8cpp_source.html#l00130):

```
# include <immintrin.h> // rdrand, MSC, ICC, and GCC
# if defined(__has_include)
#  if __has_include(<x86intrin.h>)
#   include <x86intrin.h> // rdseed for some compilers, like GCC
#  endif
# endif
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason of the same error was that Preprocessor macro name in Target Build Settings contained hyphen sign '-', something like that TEST-DEBUG=1.

[Xcode build configuration names with hyphens ('-') cause pods build failures](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2608)

Answer (score 0):

#### My case is:

`#define USE_LIBICONV  1 # xxxxxx`

#### Error

`Token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression`

#### Solution:

remove typo comments after `#define`

=> change `#` to `//`

`#define USE_LIBICONV  1 // xxxxxx`

then can use macro normally:

```
#if USE_LIBICONV
...
#endif
```