# can't use "error" per-proccessor inside "if" pre-proccessor

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

I have an enum:

```
typedef enum {
    ALI = 0,
    
    JOHN,
    CATI,

} NAMES_e;
```

As I know, as long as the enum has less than `256` items, it uses `1 byte` of RAM. The storage is so important for me, so as I'm developing the program, this might become even more than 1000 names (it might!) and I should be aware of it (To control the storage).

**1. So, I tried this in the main function:**

```
if (sizeof(NAMES_e) == 1)
    #error "NAMES_eis more than 256"
```

**2. It didn't work. I also used the same with `#if`:**

```
#if (sizeof(NAMES_e) == 1)
    #error "NAMES_eis more than 256"
#endif
```

I got this error:

> error: token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079243/how-can-i-use-sizeof-in-a-preprocessor-macro) (My compiler doesn't support `static_assert` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664830/error-token-is-not-a-valid-binary-operator-in-a-preprocessor-subexpression). Nothing special.

**3. I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497012/token-is-not-a-valid-binary-operator-in-a-preprocessor-subexpression-when-usin):**

```
int size = sizeof(NAMES_e);
size = 1; //Just to test.
#if (size == 1) 
    #error "NAMES_e is more than 256"
#endif
```

And the compiler doesn't compile the last one either. No errors while compiling.

What should I do?

Comment: You're mixing C statements and preprocessor statements. You can't do this. But anyway the size of an enum ist most likely the size of `int` even if the enum has less than 256 items.

Comment: Please check the answers on the linked question again. You can implement your own static assertion if your compiler doesn't provide one.

Comment: @KenY-N thanks. I checked that. It did not.

Comment: @Jabberwocky between 1-256, enums use 8 bits (one byte). more than 256, and less than 65536, they have to use 16 bits and so on.

Comment: @user694733 Can I? How??

Comment: @MohammadKholghi actually it depends on the platform. What is your platform?

Comment: [This answer describes BUILD_BUG_ON macro.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18511691/694733) [This CT_ASSERT macro.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19355668/694733) And there are many more similar answers in that question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm using Keil, for microcontrollers.

Comment: @user694733 I checked this site https://scaryreasoner.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/checking-sizeof-at-compile-time/ (the question redirected me), and it works for `%`, but I want it to work with `!=`.

Comment: @user694733 Problem solved. Its answer is a little bit different. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a small trick! First, I should mention that the `sizeof(char[0])` doesn't compile and throws an error. So, we take advantage of it!:

```
#define CHECK_SIZE(condition) ((void)sizeof(char[2 - (condition)]))
//...
CHECK_SIZE(sizeof(NAMES_e));
```

How does it work? If the `NAMES_e` is 2 bytes, it tries to check the `sizeof(char[0])`, which we talked about.

For more information, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18511691/9691976) and [this](https://scaryreasoner.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/checking-sizeof-at-compile-time/).